# how to convert huge Json to Array by ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have the following JSON data with more than 2000 city information. In my react app, I could use this JSON data if I can convert them in array. A similar kind of question has been asked already. But I couldn't find similarities. Because I am novice in JS and Reactjs :).

```
{
  "cities": [
    {
      "lat": "56°09'N",
      "lon": "10°13'E",
      "city": "Aarhus"
    },
    {
      "lat": "57°09'N",
      "lon": "2°07'W",
      "city": "Aberdeen"
    },
    {
      "lat": "5°19'N",
      "lon": "4°02'W",
      "city": "Abidjan"
    },
    {
      "lat": "24°28'N",
      "lon": "54°22'E",
      "city": "Abu Dhabi"
    },
}
```

Out of this json data how can I make array of city and array of lat and arry of lon?

**Updated questions:**

Since I am learning Reactjs. I intended to make select with all the available city as follows. Defiantly it is wrong. How can I do it?

```
          <div>
            <select name="city" ref={this.props.form.register}>
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            {
                myJson.cities.forEach((eaCity) => {
                    city = eaCity.city;
                    value = " "+eaCity.lat; // I need lat and lon later on as string
                    value += " "+eaCity.lon;
                    console.log("value: "+value);
                    console.log("city: "+city);
                })
            }
            <option value={value}>{city}</option> // I will store city, lat, lon after user selection. But I won't show it to the user. So I am trying to have value this way. 
        </select>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want three separate arrays? Well, let's do that:

```
const cities = [];
const lats = [];
const longs = [];
```

You want to extract values from an existing array somehow? Well, let's do that with a `forEach`:

```
// Assuming myJson.cities is the array in the "cities" field
myJson.cities.forEach((eaCity) => {
    // do something here
});
```

Hmm, what do we do in our loop? Well, let's just `push()` a new value into the three arrays we made earlier:

```
myJson.cities.forEach((eaCity) => {
    cities.push(eaCity.city);
    lats.push(eaCity.lat);
    longs.push(eaCity.long);
});
```

This all assumes that you already have the JSON data in your app. If you don't, most React app configs (webpack or Parcel) will already be set up to [load JSON files](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/):

```
import myJson from '../path/to/myJson.json';
```

Let's put it all together:

```
import myJson from '../path/to/myJson.json';

const cities = [];
const lats = [];
const longs = [];

myJson.cities.forEach((eaCity) => {
    cities.push(eaCity.city);
    lats.push(eaCity.lat);
    longs.push(eaCity.long);
});
```

Note: this method is a lot more efficient than a `.map()` because it involves only a single loop (array traverse) instead of unnecessarily traversing the same array three times. :)

Edit: Looking at your update it *seems* what you actually want to do is map over an array to render something in JSX. That is a different question entirely and not really what the first part of your question is about at all. But it should probably look something like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        <select
          name="city"
          ref={this.props.form.register}
          value={this.state.selectedValue}
          onChange={(event) => {
            this.setState({selectedValue: event.target.value});
          }}
        >
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          {
            myJson.cities.map((eaCity) => {
                return (
                  <option
                    key={eaCity.city}
                    value={`${eaCity.city} ${eaCity.lat} ${eaCity.long}`}
                  >
                    {eaCity.city}
                  </option>
                );
            })
          }
       </select>
   </div>
);
```

Note that you have to use `.map()` and not `.forEach()` in your render return because `.map()` returns a new array of some kind (ideally in this case something that can be rendered by React, like an array of components) while `.forEach()` returns undefined which is not helpful.

If this does not answer your question I really think you should open a new question specific to it and providing more details.

Comment: Very nice. I wonder is it really necessary to split this array into 3 separate ones. In the render function, since we are just going to map them to JSX, could we not just use the original array? Save us an extra loop

Comment: Efficiency in this case is negligible and readability is way more important IMO. Mapping _could be seen_ as less convoluted even if looping 3 times. But that's opinionated and differs from dev to dev.

Comment: Could you please check my updated question part? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it works but I got warning in the console due to I have the same city twice in my json data.  "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `Birmingham`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted " So how I assure unique key set for the select?

Comment: @masiboo just as the warning says, you need to ensure that the `key` prop I unique for every iteration of the map loop. So if you have two entries in the JSON array with the same city name field, they won’t all be unique and you’ll get a warning. To ensure they’re unique, try using the city + lat + long value. If it’s _still_ not unique then you actually have duplicate data in your JSON data which you should clean up in preprocessing or compute time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
let cities = cityJsonObj.cities.map(c => c.city);
let lats = cityJsonObj.cities.map(c => c.lat);
let lons = cityJsonObj.cities.map(c => c.lon);
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with React. This is simply mapping an array to different formats. What you'll want to look up for a pure understanding is javascript's [Array map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Using `map` you can create a function which will take in each value of the original array, and return a new array which is the result of that function's return value for each value of the old array.

```
const originalArray = myJson.cities;
const names = originalArray.map(cityObj => cityObj.city);
const latitudes = originalArray.map(cityObj => cityObj.lat);
const longitudes = originalArray.map(cityObj => cityObj.lon);
```

Things like `cityObj => cityObj.city` are just [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which are shorthand ways of writing functions. That would be the same as `function(cityObj) { return cityObj.city; }`

So every time you run `map` it's looping  through your array, running each value through the given function, and giving you back a new array with the result of those function calls as each value in the new array. That makes it really easy and succinct to get new arrays that are manipulations of other existing arrays.

If processing speed is a concern you also can always simply make 3 empty arrays (`names`, `latitudes`, `longitudes`) and then loop through the original array, adding each value you come across to its appropriate array using `myArray.push(valueToAdd)`. That would mean 1 loop instead of 3 (each time you map it loops through them all). But unless you're having to do this repeatedly (like if this needs to recalculate every time React renders a component) it's usually more worthwhile to keep the code succinct and just use `map`.